# compose foreach loop:@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to iterate over a `List` of objects, for each of the object I want to display a composable card. The problem is that you cant call Composable functions from inside the `list.forEach{}`  brackets.

The Code:

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(listy : List<SomethingForLater>) {
  LazyColumn {
    listy.forEach {
        //error here
        testCard(somethingForLater = it)
        }

    }
}
@Composable
fun testCard(somethingForLater: SomethingForLater){
val theme = MaterialTheme
Card(shape = theme.shapes.small,backgroundColor = theme.colors.secondary){
    Column {
        Row {
            Text(
                text = somethingForLater.task,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 5.dp,
                    top = 3.dp,bottom = 3.dp
                ),
                fontSize = 18.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,

                )
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is `items` parameter in `LazyColumn`

```
LazyColumn {
        items(listy) { message ->
            testCard(message)
        }
    }
```

Or you can simply change `LazyColumn` to `Column`

Answer (score 15):

`LazyColumn` does not provide any composable content. So you have to wrap your composable functions inside `items` parameter.

```
@Composable
fun Greetings(listy : List<SomethingForLater>) {
  LazyColumn {
    items(listy.size) {
      listy.forEach { somethingForLater ->
        TestCard(somethingForLater = somethingForLater)
      }
    }
  }
}
```